# Test Push notification on TestFlight

Tags: apple-push-notifications, testflight

I created a app that use remote push notification, on development mode worked very well, I need to send to some people test on TestFlight.
My doubt, I change the push notification to production or stay on development?

Comment: what is the problem in switching notification mode to production?

Comment: there is not problem to switching notification mode to production, I need to know if TestFlight works on development mode

Comment: I am really not sure but I think that you need production certificate for pushes when you want to use them  on any devices. TestFlight is the alternative distribution way so I think that certificate for pushes must be the same for both AppStore and TestFlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a AdHoc and worked very well using production ssl to push notification on TestFlight